# C#: Will Console.WriteLine be removed during optimization by compiler in Web Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, compiler-optimization

I want to use `Console.WriteLine()` as a dummy instruction to avoid optimization of exception varibale `e` in below structure.

```
try
{
}catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "");//dummy command to avoid optimization 
                                      //and removal of unused variable e
}
```

I want to know if `Console.WriteLine()` instruction will be kept after optimization of web-application code or not?

Comment: why would you assume that it should remove it? What if you redirect Console.Out stream to some other target, and then compiler would just cut off this code? you might want to use compiler preprocessor variables, if you don't want to have this method invocation in release build

Comment: In this particular example you've shown, the Console.WriteLine is playing an important role in letting you have visibility into what went wrong. You really should use a logging library like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/). Then you can use a single statement to log to the console, a file, a database, or something more specialized like [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq). And you can control with configuration which it uses at any given time.

Comment: in web application there is no `console`, the iis is a service that have no user interface - why not use this `debug.writeline` ? You can also make some global static function that do nothing,